# Jquery - Calling a Function from a button created with a function

Tags: jquery, function, button, click

this works in Jquery :

```
<input type="button" class="go" value="GO" />

$(".go").click(function() {
$("#test").html("TEST TEST TEST");
});
```

But if I try to access the go function from a button created using the following it fails.

```
$(".new").click(function() {
$.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("data-value"),
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        $('#DIV').html('<input type="button" class="go" value="go" />');
    }
}
 });
});
```

This code is used when another function click function completes.

Any reason why ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes.  Your code using `.click` binds only to elements that exist at the time the code is run.  You want something like `.live` (deprecated, but documentation shows current proper methods) which binds to elements that may be created later...

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

**As you are creating button dynamically.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container.

Example

```
$('#DIV').on('click', '.go', function () {
    //Your Code     
});
```

Comment: Why is it needed to use event delegation? (I know, but it would be good to explain why in the answer....)

Comment: I know the answer.  Your additional sentence helps, but doesn't make it as clear as it could be.