# Click events on dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, web

I am building a web app, and the UI will have some dynamically created buttons. I struggled with click events on those buttons, but made it work by having click events on static  tags that dynamically filled.

While this works, it doesn't seem like a great way to do this.

Is there a more semantic way of doing this? Or better still, a way to directly click the dynamically created button, and have a function triggered?

Comment: Learn [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Visit this [Might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389374/jquery-calling-a-function-from-a-button-created-with-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-class', function() {
    // Clicked!
});
```

Comment: This worked for me,  and is much cleaner than the way I was getting it done thanks!